# LTspice - move the cursor to a particular run in the plot

Tags: ltspice, plot, parameters

After running a stepped parameter simulation, the cursor can be moved between different runs using the up and down arrows. This is impractical for a large number of runs. Is there a way to jump to e.g. run 152 without plodding through the runs one by one? And all this while leaving all the runs visible for comparison?

BTW: Actually, this can be done by right-clicking in the plot, View ---> Select Steps. The step in question is selected and cursor added, and after selecting all the steps the cursor stays at that previously selected step. But I still hope there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: Hmm, not that I know of - maybe another workaround would be to plot everything and plot the same value only for one step and attach the cursor to that line.

Comment: But that turns of the color cycling for the multi step trace - makes it kind of hard to see.

Comment: That's the way, through *Select Steps*. There is no way any program can read minds on where to place the cursor first and, if you say there are plenty of traces, then it might already be cumbersom to click for a specific trace. You could have something like select the traces by clicking on them, and it might be a worthwile feature to add -- for which you could try mailing ADI in the *Help > About* address.

Comment: If run 152 is the one of most interest, can you structure your parameter sweeps to force that to be the 1st run instead?

Comment: @SteKulov Good thing I saw this in time. This entry in the *Changelog.txt* might provide the answer: `05/16/18 The first .step dimension is now reordered to be increasing.`. Whatever values the `.step` uses, all of them will be ordered in ascending order. Personally, I don't agree, but it's also something that's not likely to change anytime soon (if ever).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen If that only applies to the first dimension, could you have a dummy first dimension with just one entry and have the *second* dimension be ordered the way you want?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I also know for a fact that it's just the values the .step command outputs that are reordered; you're free to have another .param statement transform them however you like. So if you have `.step param A list 3 2 1` giving you 1 2 3, you could instead do `.step param B list 1 2 3` along with `.param A={4-B)`, which will make A be 3 2 1.

Comment: @Hearth Sure, that's the way to circumvent it. That's why I mentioned about the values of the `.step`, not anything else. Not lastly, it's far more tedious for users to concoct up cures than it is for the program to simply allow the `.step` command function as was intended... but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Oh I agree, it ought to allow you to put them in whatever order you want.